# Git: stage only added lines of a files

Tags: git

I'm running a script that generates code (string constant) from a text file (representing a tree).

Running the script deletes constants that are used elsewhere in the codebase.

I'd like to not commit the deleted lines (because it will break other teams code) and instead mark those constant as deprecated.

Is there a way to stage only "added" lines in my generated files ?

I can do it with `git add -p` but it's a bit tedious since I have several files, with lot of changes.

Input diff:

```
const string Namespace1::kProperty1 = "/namespace_1/property_1";
+ const string Namespace1::kProperty2 = "/namespace_1/property_2";

const string Namespace2::kProperty3 = "/namespace_2/property_3";
- const string Namespace2::kProperty2 = "/namespace_2/property_2";
```

Expected commit diff:

```
const string Namespace1::kProperty1 = "/namespace_1/property_1";
+ const string Namespace1::kProperty2 = "/namespace_1/property_2";

const string Namespace2::kProperty3 = "/namespace_2/property_3";
const string Namespace2::kProperty2 = "/namespace_2/property_2";
```

Comment: You will need to get a graphical client. Other than `git add -p` there is no good built-in option, other than to manually edit back in the lines that were deleted. If you have a good diff program, like Beyond Compare, that supports editing, and set up a fresh unmodified copy, you can use the diff program to compare the fresh copy against your working folder and bring back every line that was deleted.

Comment: Additionally, and in my mind this is a far better option. If you're not supposed to delete things from those files, fix your generation script so that it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one tool does this, but several can work together.

- [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) is included in the standard Python library and produces output that is easier to consume than the `diff` command.
- `git cat-file blob ...` retrieves content from the Git database without modifying the working tree.
- If you're not using a shell like Bash that lets you do `<()` process substitution, you could move it into Python with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) or use a temporary file.
- `git hash-object -t blob -w` writes an object back to the Git database.
- `git update-index --cacheinfo 100644,...` updates the index/stage, again without touching the working tree.

That should give similar results to a `git add -p` operation.

```
git update-index --cacheinfo 100644,$(python -c '
    import difflib, sys;
    sys.stdout.writelines(
        line[2:] for line in difflib.Differ().compare(
            open(sys.argv[1]).readlines(), open(sys.argv[2]).readlines())
        if line.startswith("  ") or line.startswith("+ "))' \
    <(git cat-file blob HEAD:filename) filename \
| git hash-object -t blob -w --stdin --path filename),filename
```

Comment: Thanks, you set me in the right direction. But you need to print ALL  the lines in the diff, since I also want the deleted lines. Also the use of python is really convenient if you want to generate "deprecated" comments at the same time.